# PostgreSQL return tuples where another column is not null

Tags: sql

Let’s say I have a table

```
Name age
A    Null
B    Null
B    7
C    9
C    8
```

How can I write a sql query to return

```
Name 
C
```

Meaning that only names where there is no null value in age are returned? Specifically using Postgres

Thoughts so far:

I think doing select name from table where age is not null, returns B and C because B has one age that isn’t null. So then, I thought about grouping by name but aggregation seems to remove bulls. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do you have an additional primary key (or unique) column?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what dbms you are using, you can use `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT name FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(ISNULL(age)) = 0
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh Both MySQL and MSSQL, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. `COUNT(age)` counts non-null values. `COUNT(*)` counts all rows.

```
SELECT name
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(age) = COUNT(*)
```

Or do an `EXCEPT` query:

```
SELECT name FROM table
EXCEPT
SELECT name FROM table WHERE age IS NULL
```

Comment: Also except is dbms specific ;)

Comment: :) It's actually ANSI/ISO SQL standard. (The <sql> tag says "_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._") However, there are products not supporting it - so it's a good idea avoiding it when writing SQL supposed to be portable!

Comment: @dcolazin:  `EXCEPT` has been part of the SQL standard for about 30 years